# Intermediate CA does not create tls-cert.pem

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to create Intermediate CA using Root CA, My folder structure for ROOT CA and Intermediate CA  is as shown below.  Steps  which I am using to create the intermediate ca is

1. Running the instance of ROOT CA with tls-enable. which create all the fabric-ca server file inside the Org1CA
2. I am copying the `tls-cert.pem` file inside the ICA folder.
3. I am using the init command for intermediate ca which will generate all the fabric CA server files inside the ICA folder with `chain-ca.pem`.
4. I am starting the fabric intermediate CA instance with command start in docker-compose.yaml it's working.

   I am facing issue when I start the intermediate instance its does not create **tls-cert.pem** and when I enrol the peers with ORG1CA tls-cert.pem and run the peer containers I am facing  `TLS handshaking error`.

```
    fabric-ca
        Org1CA
        ICA
```

ROOT CA

```
version: "2"

networks:
  test:

services:
  ca_org1:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:$IMAGE_TAG
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=7054
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ../organizations/fabric-ca/org1:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
    container_name: ca_org1
    networks:
      - test
```

INTERMEDIATE CA

```
version: "2"

networks:
  test:

services:
  ica-org1:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ica-org1
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=debug
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=6054
    ports:
      - "6054:6054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start  -b icaadmin:icaadminpw -u -d http://ica:icapw@ca-org1:7054'
    volumes:
      - ../organizations/fabric-ca/icaOrg1:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
    container_name: ica-org1
    networks:
     - test
```

NodeOUs

```
echo 'NodeOUs:
  Enable: true
  ClientOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/localhost-7054-ca-org1.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: client
  PeerOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/localhost-7054-ca-org1.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: peer
  AdminOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/localhost-7054-ca-org1.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: admin
  OrdererOUIdentifier:
    Certificate: cacerts/localhost-7054-ca-org1.pem
    OrganizationalUnitIdentifier: orderer' > ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp/config.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

If ICA do not generate `tls-cert.pem` in FABRIC_CA_HOME folder, try use chain-cert.pem. Do not use certificate of RCA. Because peer enroll to ICA => only ICA cert can verify cert of peer.

Comment: thank you for replay, does tls-cert.pem and chain-cert.pem both work has same ?

Comment: I am not sure it work in all case. But I had replaced all tls-cert.pem to ca-cert.pem in test-network of fabric-samples and network successfully created. In my project, I only use ca-cert.pem of RCA and ca-chain.pem of ICA with TLS enable.

Comment: Thank you I'll try and update here, one more thing, if you check above I have updated ```NodeOUs``` do I need to change it from ```cacerts/localhost-7054-ca-org1.pem``` to ```intermidiatecerts/``` folder

Comment: it's not working for me ```fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://peer1:peer1pw@localhost:4054 --caname ica.org1.avantas.com -M ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.avantas.com/peers/peer1.org1.avantas.com/tls --enrollment.profile tls --csr.hosts peer1.org1.example.com --csr.hosts localhost --tls.certfiles ${PWD}/organizations/fabric-ca/icaorg1/ca-cert.pem' ```

Comment: I think it name is "ca-chain.pem" not "ca-cert.pem". Show me all tree structure folder of "${PWD}/organizations/fabric-ca/icaorg1". And show me command you use to init ICA.

Comment: I have updated my question with intermediate folder structure image and steps which i using to generating ICA

Comment: I have used ```--tls.certfiles ${PWD}/organizations/fabric-ca/icaorg1/ca-chain.pem``` after using it, when I run peer container I can tls handshake error.   But I am deleting  the ROOT CA MSP before I enrol the Intermediate CA, admin

Comment: Do you mean you still have error "tls handshake error" when start peer? Btw you need change NodeOUs to intermidiatecerts/ to starting peer successfully. In step c, I think "copy all the tls-cert file from org1 to icaorg1 folder" is unnecessary.

Comment: I change 'NodeOUs'  to ```intermediatecerts/localhost-4054-ica-org1-example-com.pem``` still facing tls hand shake issue.

Comment: Okay, I ll commit and update here link here thank you. One more thing how tls certificate is derived from intermediate ca. How i can check tls belongs to intermidiate ca

Comment: You can display information about your tls cert by using "openssl x509 -text -noout -in <your_cert>"